# Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer): Heroku Rails app Devise mailer error when creating user in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, smtp

My ruby on rails app breaks when making a new user deployed to production.

User seems to be created according to logs yet email is not actually delivered and web app breaks.
Only thing I can come up with is that the host/mail server is closing my connection when the mailer tries to sign in.

Any suggestions ? I am going to try to use "send grid" and see if that makes it go away however their approval process is taking longer than expected in the meantime i'd like to see if I can solve this without having to use "send grid".

I am using devise for authentication and devise mailer to mail a welcome email upon user creation.
I am using a privateemail.com email account with my custom domain to send the email.
I have checked my credentials and they are correct.
The settings for the mailer are as follows. I used the suggested smtp settings from namecheap.com.

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,  
  :address            => 'mail.privateemail.com',
  :port               => 465,
  :tls                  => false,
  :domain             => 'customdomain.com', 
  :authentication     => :plain,
  :user_name          => ENV['EMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password           => ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
}


  # config.action_mailer_host 
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'customdomain.com'}
```

```
2022-06-30T06:42:37.359757+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-30T06:42:37.359677 #8]  INFO -- : [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] Delivered mail 62bd45d32e788_865e059762@08b9bfd2-c02f-4379-9217-508e97422a06.mail (10171.1ms)
2022-06-30T06:42:37.360082+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-30T06:42:37.360036 #8]  INFO -- : [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10514ms (ActiveRecord: 26.8ms | Allocations: 14371)
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361221+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-30T06:42:37.361158 #8] FATAL -- : [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff]
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361222+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer):
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361223+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff]
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361223+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/socket.rb:452:in `__read_nonblock'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361223+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/socket.rb:452:in `read_nonblock'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361224+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:212:in `rbuf_fill'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361224+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:193:in `readuntil'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361224+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:203:in `readline'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361225+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/smtp.rb:984:in `recv_response'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361225+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/smtp.rb:592:in `block in do_start'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361225+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/smtp.rb:994:in `critical'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361225+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/smtp.rb:592:in `do_start'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361226+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] vendor/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/smtp.rb:557:in `start'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361226+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] mail (2.7.1) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:109:in `start_smtp_session'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361226+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] mail (2.7.1) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:100:in `deliver!'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361227+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] mail (2.7.1) lib/mail/message.rb:2159:in `do_delivery'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361227+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] mail (2.7.1) lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `block in deliver'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361227+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionmailer (6.1.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:559:in `block in deliver_mail'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361228+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361228+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361229+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361229+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionmailer (6.1.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:557:in `deliver_mail'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361229+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] mail (2.7.1) lib/mail/message.rb:260:in `deliver'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361229+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionmailer (6.1.4) lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:119:in `block in deliver_now'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361230+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionmailer (6.1.4) lib/action_mailer/rescuable.rb:17:in `handle_exceptions'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361230+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionmailer (6.1.4) lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:118:in `deliver_now'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361231+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] devise (4.8.0) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:204:in `send_devise_notification'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361231+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] devise (4.8.0) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:121:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361231+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] devise (4.8.0) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:183:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361232+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361232+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:260:in `block in conditional'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361232+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:516:in `block in invoke_after'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361232+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:516:in `each'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361232+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:516:in `invoke_after'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361233+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:107:in `run_callbacks'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361233+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:824:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361233+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:321:in `committed!'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361237+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:155:in `commit_records'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361238+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:304:in `block in commit_transaction'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361239+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361239+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361239+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361240+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361240+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361240+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:294:in `commit_transaction'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361241+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:351:in `block in within_new_transaction'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361241+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361241+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361241+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361242+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361242+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361243+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361243+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361243+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:350:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361244+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:298:in `save'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361244+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361244+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] devise (4.8.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:19:in `create'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361244+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361245+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361245+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361245+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361245+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361246+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actiontext (6.1.4) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361246+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actiontext (6.1.4) lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361246+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361246+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361249+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361249+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361249+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361250+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361250+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361250+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361251+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361251+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361251+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361251+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activerecord (6.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361252+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361252+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionview (6.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361252+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361253+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361253+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361253+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361254+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361254+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361254+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361255+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361255+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361255+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361256+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361256+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361256+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361257+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361257+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361257+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361258+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361258+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361258+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361259+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361259+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361259+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361259+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361260+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361262+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361263+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361263+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361263+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361263+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361264+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361264+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361264+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361264+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361265+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361265+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361265+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361266+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361266+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361266+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] activesupport (6.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361266+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361267+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361267+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361267+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:77:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361267+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] actionpack (6.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:92:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361268+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] railties (6.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361268+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361268+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361269+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:338:in `with_force_shutdown'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361269+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361269+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
2022-06-30T06:42:37.361269+00:00 app[web.1]: [0b4db766-b2d9-401d-b8f3-5f46759967ff] puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue since a few weeks ago. Never happened before... Have you found something that can fix this ?

Comment: No i didnt find a solution and ended using sendgrid.